# Why is pi used to represent prime numbers here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've just begun the "Concrete Mathematics" book by Knuth et al. In the first section about sums (and I apologise if this is really trivial, but I'm new and struggling a little);
and they show this as one of the examples:

$\sum_{k = 1}^{\pi(N)}  \frac{1}{p_{k}}$

"This is the sum of all reciprocals of prime numbers between 1 and N."

If you didn't have the explanation here, how would you know that N is supposed to be a prime number? Is it because of the pi symbol? Also, does pi often represent a number as prime?

Comment: Not that it's relevant to this question, but in fact in Algebraic Number Theory one often uses $\pi$ to stand for a prime number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Nono, I appreciate your time, and in fact I was stressing over some phantom relationship between the number $\pi$ and the symbol used in this case. So that does help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\pi(N)$ is the [prime-counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), i.e. the number of primes not exceeding $N$.

Comment: Both useful answers but I'm going to choose this as my correct answer because the further reading provided helped me a lot. Thank you both!

Answer (score 6):

$N$ is not supposed to be a prime number. $\pi(N)$ denotes the number of primes $\leq N$ and is (obviously) a function of $N$. Similarly, $p_k$ is the $k$th prime .